# UART debug session in Keil for KL25Z

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, uart

The program is to receive a byte from the host PC via `UART0` on `KL25Z`. The data is fetched from Data Register `D` and assigned to a variable, `c`. Then controlled by the value of each bit of `c`, tri-color LEDs are lightened. The program works well with no problem.

When Keil enters ‘debug session’, I set a breakpoint to observe `c` and `UART0->D`.

```
[code][1]

[watch c][2]
```

After sending a byte from a terminal emulator software on PC, the program stops at the breaking point as `RDRF` (Receive Data Register Full) flags. At this moment, it can be observed data in Data Register is `0x61` which is the ascii code of letter ‘a’ and there is no value in variable, `c`.

```
[UART0_D][3]
[watch c][4]
```

If stepping by one line, variable `c` is supposed to be equal to `0x61`. However, the result is `c` is `0` and Data Register is emptied. Because `c` is `0`, LEDs are not lightened accordingly. I don’t understand why?

```
[UART0_D][5]
[watch c][6]
```

The setting for debug is as follows.

```
[debugger selection][7]
[debugger settings][8]
```

I'm running short of 10 reputation points to post more than 2 links. Relative images are attached here. Sorry for the inconvenience.

[image link](https://motognere.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/uart-debug-problem-in-keil-for-kl25z/)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have all optimization off?

Comment: Yes, optimization level is 0.

Comment: Weird...  the rx data register must have been read since it got emptied, but the data has disappeared from 'c' :(  Must be some debugger artifact:(  Can you read the rx data in asembler instead of C, just for debug purposes?

Comment: Try stepping through the code without watching the UART Data register.  If you have the register window open in the debugger then the debugger reads the registers every time it halts.  If the register value is automatically reset when it is read then your subsequent code may not get the same value that was shown in the debugger's register watch window.  You have to be aware and careful when watching register values that are affected by a read.  The read performed for the watch window is an extra read.

Comment: @MartinJames Just as you said, I have the same confusion. I'm not skilled at assembly. But the assembly code of reading data register can be found from the debug session as follows: 0x0000033C 4802      LDR      r0,[pc,#8]  ; at0x00000348   0x0000033E 79C3      LDRB     r3,[r0,#0x07]

Comment: @kkrambo Thanks a lot. The problem is solved by your advice.